# Fourier transform of a cosine

Tags: integration, fourier-transform

I'm trying to wrap my head around the following.

I understand the steps that lead from
$$x(y)=A \cos(2 \pi f_0 t)$$
to 
$$X(y)=A \frac{\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0)}{2}$$

$f_0$ is the carrier frequency.

The problem I have is that I would expect the integration of cosine from -$\infty$ to $\infty$ to "blow".

Comment: It only makes sense as a distribution.

Comment: @copper.hat Even more precisely, it makes sense as a "[Tempered Distribution](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Distribution_(mathematics)#Tempered_distributions_and_Fourier_transform)."

Comment: @Dr.MV: Thanks!

Comment: Dirac delta is the "blow".

Comment: You know that $\widehat{g(t)h(t)}(f) = \widehat{g(t)} \ast \widehat{h(t)}(f)$. Here, $\widehat{\cos(t)}(f) = \frac{\delta(f-1)+\delta(f+1)}{2}$ because for any $h(t)$ such that $\widehat{h}(f)$ is well-defined, you have $\widehat{h(t)\cos(t)}(f) = \widehat{h} \ast \frac{\delta(f-1)+\delta(f+1)}{2} = \frac{\widehat{h}(f-1)+\widehat{h}(f+1)}{2}$

Answer (score 0):

Through Euler, we have:

$$A\cos(2\pi f_0t)=\frac{A}{2}\left[e^{j2\pi f_0t}+e^{-j2\pi f_0t}\right]$$

Ok, now there is an important property of Dirac's Delta function regarding its integration:

$$\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(x\pm x_0)f(x)dx=f(\mp x_0)$$

Then, by inspection of the Euler form of the cosine, we have:

$$e^{j2\pi f_0t}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(f-f_0)e^{j2\pi ft}df$$

and

$$e^{-j2\pi f_0t}=\int_{-\infty}^{+\infty}\delta(f+f_0)e^{j2\pi ft}df$$

Which are, clearly, the inverse Fourier Transforms of $\delta(f-f_0)$ and $\delta(f+f_0)$. So:

$$\frac{A}{2}\left[e^{j2\pi f_0t}+e^{-j2\pi f_0t}\right]\stackrel{\mathcal{F}}\longleftrightarrow \frac{A}{2}\left[\delta(f-f_0)+\delta(f+f_0)\right]$$

This is also the procedure used for $A\sin(2\pi f_0t)$, giving:

$$\frac{A}{2j}\left[e^{j2\pi f_0t}-e^{-j2\pi f_0t}\right] \stackrel{\mathcal{F}}\longleftrightarrow \frac{A}{2j}\left[\delta(f-f_0)-\delta(f+f_0)\right]$$